# Reference a string from resources to the interface

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have an app that requires a subscription key to be placed in the request header. Is there a way that I could reference the key from the string resources to the interface.

Given this code

```
public interface apiService { 
    @Headers({
            "Content-Type: application/octet-stream",
            "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 194bcbe84a424c8d9c7378cc9e5fa41d"//key
    })
    @POST("vision/v1.0/analyze")
    Call<visualFeatures_Description> uploadImage(@Body RequestBody imageFile);
}
```

I'd like to upload the repository to Github and add the xml file of the resource to the .gitignore so my key won't be visible.

I tried using

```
getString(R.strings.key)
```

inside the interface, but it says I cannot reference from a static context.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Resources.getSystem().getString(R.strings.key)
```

You can use it just about anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

you should use  `Application` class.

```
public class AppController extends Application {

private static Context mContext;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mContext = this;
}

public static Context getContext(){
    return mContext;
}
}
```

now you can access the `resources` like this..

```
 AppController.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.key);
```

Do not forget to add this class in `Manifest.xml`  like

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:name=".AppController"  <!--Here you can see this -->
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Hi Devendera, I tried to follow your answer but when I try to use 'AppController.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.key);' inside the Retrofit interface method, it says cannot resolve symbol 'getContext()'.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use BuildConfig fields :

```
buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", '"key"'
```

Which you can then access anywhere with `BuildConfig.API_KEY` (if this field isn't available, try doing a Clean and Rebuild)

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode buildVersionCode
        versionName buildVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", '"my_key_here"'
    }
```